# Should I use BIT(1) or BOOL?

Tags: mysql

Mysql has two types that can hold boolean data, bit and bool. Bit(1) seems more logical, because that has to be 1 or 0, bool is, according to the specs, the same as saying tinyint(1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For keeping things semi-universal / portable across other database vendors, use BIT.  MySQL's a step ahead of most servers by even allowing the BOOLEAN keyword.

See: [Comparison of different SQL implementations](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#data_types-boolean)

Answer (score 5):

*Au contraire*, bool seems much more logical, especially if you want to record truth and falsity.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on your application and client library.  Some database abstraction layers might expect that a boolean is a type of integer. (I know, technically a bit is an integer)

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to use the `CHAR(0)` type. A column that is defined as `CHAR(0) NULL`  occupies only one bit and can take only the values NULL and '' (the empty string).

This is documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-type-overview.html